# How can I achieve a scikit-learn confusion matrix without extra columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I have a classifier that does binary classification. For training I take the data I trust.
For testing, I take the data I trust and also some not so good data (real world data).

**How do I get a confusion matrix without extra columns?**

Here is my test code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

y_test = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
predictions = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)

l = ["M", "F", "M?", "F?"]
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=l)
disp.plot()
plt.show()
# I expect a 4x2 matrix here. How can I do it?
```

[See? Unnecessary columns are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8reXC.png)

**Am I missing something?**

## **Feel free to say that I am completely wrong.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because you said "... my question ishow to make a 4x2 matrix." on comments I wrote this:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


y_test = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
predictions = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
unique_labels = sorted(set(y_test + predictions))

# Manually create a 4x2 confusion matrix
conf_matrix = np.zeros((len(unique_labels), 2), dtype=int)

# Fill in the confusion matrix based on true labels and predictions
for true_label, pred_label in zip(y_test, predictions):
    conf_matrix[true_label, pred_label] += 1

display_labels = ["M", "F", "M?", "F?"]
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap="Blues", xticklabels=["M", "F"], yticklabels=display_labels)

plt.xlabel("Predicted Label")
plt.ylabel("True Label")
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

**However I feel like you want this 2x4 instead (As your question was a bit vague) :**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_test = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
predictions = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
unique_labels = sorted(set(y_test + predictions))

# Manually create a 2x4 confusion matrix
conf_matrix = np.zeros((len(unique_labels), 2), dtype=int)

# Fill in the confusion matrix based on true labels and predictions
for true_label, pred_label in zip(y_test, predictions):
    conf_matrix[true_label, pred_label] += 1

display_labels = ["M", "F", "M?", "F?"]
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix.T, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap="Blues", xticklabels=display_labels, yticklabels=["M", "F"])

plt.xlabel("True Label")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Label")
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: yes, this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

It give you 4 columns because in your y_test you don't have a binary information (not only 0 or 1).

So basically your ground truth seems to be a ground truth for a multiclass classification (int from 0 to 3).

For example, if you replace your 2 and 3 in y_pred by 0 or 1 you will have a 2x2 matrix as you desire.

Comment: That's true, but my question is more about how to make a 4x2 matrix.

Comment: A confusion matrix is always a square one, see this source : [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-dimensions-of-a-confusion-matrix) and [Toward Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/avoiding-confusion-with-confusion-matrix-metrics-a8a3d0ead144). So I don't really understand what you want to compute with the two last rows. Especially, a confusion matrix for a binary classification is a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).